# Iterating Python Array

Tags: python, loops, logic

I have a logic error in the following code:

```
while count < 5:
    row = next(csv_f)
    if row[0] != currentID:
        userArray.append(Users(row[0]))
        currentID = row[0]
        count = count+1

    userArray[len(userArray)-1].addUsageData(row[1],row[3])
```

It loops through each user until the ID changes and does this a total of five times.

Everything works, but the last index in the usage array that I get from row[1] is always the first in the next userID block. It's as if the len(userArray) is not updating when the if block is executed.

Comment: Try to print len(userArray) before and after. Make an effort to actually debug,

Comment: The source of the problem is not obvious from the code you posted. Can you prepare a runnable example which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @flyinghigh if you add element into list - length increases. You are saying it is not, because you append in if. I am extremely sceptical you encountered Python bug. Put print statement after each line with meaningful info I am pretty sure you will resolve the problem in 5 minutes this way.

Comment: Python bug or my bug?

Comment: So there are 276 rows for one index of the array and the length are correct. But, at the end, when the new index is added, it still says length one! 

274
This is len 1
275
This is len 1
276
This is len 1
1
This is len 2

Answer (score 0):

When `row[0] != currentID` for the final time, `count` is increment to 5. This
breaks you out of the `while-loop` immediately, **before** any subsequent rows
in `csv_f` are processed. If `addUsageData` is accumulating data, this is why the final `user` only has data for one row.

You could fix this problem by using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
import itertools as IT
import operator

userArray = []
for currentID, grp in IT.islice(IT.groupby(csv_f, key=operator.itemgetter(0)), 5):
    user = Users(currentID)
    userArray.append(user)
    for row in grp:
        user.addUsageData(row[1], row[3])
```

Comment: But he has different indentation in the question.

Comment: @Andrey: The OP says he is believes there is a logic error in his code. I believe the logic error is due to incorrect indentation.

Comment: Yeah that is what I initially thought but this doesn't exactly fits description of his problem. Anyway description of the problem is very vague.

Comment: In the csv there are columns of the same userId. So I only want to create a new User object when the ID changes. But I do want data added for each iteration of the loop. It just tacks on the first of the new id to the last of the old id.